# Multiple MDM profiles in same iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, mdm

Can multiple MDM profiles from different organizations be installed in the same iPhone at the same time?

Is there any document that explains this?

What is limited MDM profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't install multiple MDM on iOS.

If you try to install it will try to replace the old one (and there are some rules when it's allowed or not).